# Model matrix for linear model with multiple contrasts

Tags: r, linear-model

I don't fully understand the concept of a `model.matrix`. Assume I have the following experimental design:

```
   Outcome
s1      t1
s2      t1
s3      nc
s4      nc
s5      t2
s6      t2
s7      ex
s8      ex
```

Each row corresponds to a sample and the outcome is either normal control (`nc`), treatment 1 (`t1`), treatment 2 (`t1`), or the sample should be excluded from the analysis (`ex`). I would like to compare `nc` vs `t1` and `nc` vs `t2`.

What is the correct `model.matrix` for this data and how can I generate it using R?

The experimental design can be created using `data.frame(Outcome = c("t1","t1","nc","nc","t2","t2","ex","ex"), row.names = paste0("s",1:8))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Cliff mentions in their answer, the model matrix allows a comparison between different groups. Given my initial question, the model matrix for this experiment is:

```
myData <- data.frame(Outcome = c("t1","t1","nc","nc","t2","t2","ex","ex"), 
row.names = paste0("s",1:8))
mm <- model.matrix(~0 + Outcome, myData)

mm
   Outcomeex Outcomenc Outcomet1 Outcomet2
s1         0         0         1         0
s2         0         0         1         0
s3         0         1         0         0
s4         0         1         0         0
s5         0         0         0         1
s6         0         0         0         1
s7         1         0         0         0
s8         1         0         0         0
```

Unlike Cliff's answer, this will produce a `model.matrix` without an intercept. The contrast matrix associated with this experiment should be:

```
           Contrasts
Levels      Outcomet1 - Outcomenc Outcomet2 - Outcomenc
  Outcomeex                     0                     0
  Outcomenc                    -1                    -1
  Outcomet1                     1                     0
  Outcomet2                     0                     1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking what does `model.matrix` do to allow us to compare different groups.

In most (all?) linear models, the way we compare categorical variables is to add dummy variables (i.e. values that are just 0 or 1) that represent whether that subject belongs to that given group. Then, if we want to know the difference between subjects of group X and the baseline group, the covariate associated with group X will represent this difference.

You can see the creation of these dummy variables very easily from the code you've written:

`myData <- data.frame(Outcome = c("t1","t1","nc","nc","t2","t2","ex","ex"), 
row.names = paste0("s",1:8))`

`model.matrix(~Outcome, data = myData)`

Note that `model.matrix` automatically makes our dummy variables for us, so the output is immediately ready to be plugged into some sort of algorithm that accepts only numeric values.